# How to partially split string elements of a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of email addresses, and I want to search which are the most used email providers (eg. gmail.com, yahoo.com etc). I used the following code

```
dfEmail=Ecom['Email']
```

I have the following data

```
0                    pdunlap@yahoo.com

1                   anthony41@reed.com

2       amymiller@morales-harrison.com

3          brent16@olson-robinson.info

4          christopherwright@gmail.com

...              

9995            iscott@wade-garner.com

9996                mary85@hotmail.com

9997                 tyler16@gmail.com

9998           elizabethmoore@reid.net

9999             rachelford@vaughn.com

Name: Email, Length: 10000, dtype: object
```

I want to split these email addresses at "@" and get only names of email providers.

I tried the following

```
dfEmailSplit=dfEmail.str.split('@')
dfEmailSplit[500][1]
```

this gave me the following result:

```
'gmail.com'
```

How do i do this for all the email addresses?

Comment: for accessing indexes of a list, you can use pandas `str` accessor: `dfEmail.str.split('@').str[1]`

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved the problem! Cheers

Comment: Apologies to @anky, saw your post after posting an answer.

Comment: @SeyiDaniel No problem :) However it is a dupe hence commented

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd     
df = pd.DataFrame() 
data = {'email':['pdunlap@yahoo.com', 'anthony41@reed.com', 'amymiller@morales- harrison.com']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
tlds = {'tlds': [x.split('@')[1] for x in df['email']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(tlds)  
print(df)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Noted. Thanks.